# Navigation Within A Document

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, blogger

I'm doing the **'Navigation Within A Document'** thing but I can't make it slide through the webpage. [Here you have a link to my blog](http://edlpdaniela.blogspot.com.ar/). When you click on 'Staff', the link drives you to the staff section. But I want it to slide through the webpage and lead you to that section, just like the scrollbar does.

Any code ideas?

```
<li><a href='#staff'>Staff</a></li>

<a name="staff"> The staff div would be here </a>
```

Comment: You need to use a smooth-scroll plugin as Preben has stated below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is your answer: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

See demo here: http://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the `<a>` element. In your blog it works because the `staff` container has enough height to scroll to this position.

To do the effect you need like this:

```
<li><a href='#staff'>Staff</a></li>

<a name="staff" style="display: block; height: 1000px;"> The staff div would be here </a>
```

Of course it is a dummy example, but it shows why not works in your example.